# WCF custom service host factory not being called

Tags: wcf, dependency-injection, .net-4.5

I've implemented a WCF Service Library (.Net 4.5) which works fine.
Then I tried to implement Unity DI using a custom Servcie Host Factory. Debugging application I noticed that CreateServiceHost method in my factory not being called so that my service constructor which uses a dependency as parameter not being called and I get this error:

"System.InvalidOperationException: The service type provided could not be loaded as a service because it does not have a default (parameter-less) constructor. To fix the problem, add a default constructor to the type, or pass an instance of the type to the host."

my custom Service Host Factory:

```
namespace Amir.CodingChallenge.WcfService.Unity
{
    public class UnityServiceHostFactory : ServiceHostFactory
    {
        protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
        {
            UnityServiceHost serviceHost = new UnityServiceHost(serviceType,baseAddresses);


            // I register types in RegisterComponents method by coding.
            serviceHost.Container = UnityConfig.RegisterComponents();


            return serviceHost;
        }
    }
}
```

my service:

```
namespace Amir.CodingChallenge.WcfService
{
    public class MovieService : IMovieService
    {
        IShowService showService;

        public MovieService(IShowService showService)
        {
            this.showService = showService;
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

and App.Config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
      <serviceActivations>
        <add service="Amir.CodingChallenge.WcfService.MovieService"
             relativeAddress="./MovieService.svc"
             factory="Amir.CodingChallenge.WcfService.Unity.UnityServiceHostFactory"/>
      </serviceActivations>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
    <services>
      <service name="Amir.CodingChallenge.WcfService.MovieService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="Amir.CodingChallenge.WcfService.IMovieService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:49875/Amir.CodingChallenge.WcfService/MovieService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

"Amir.CodingChallenge.WcfService" is my app Assembly name.
Am I doing something wrong in config? Any help would be appreciated.

And the rest of my codes to give further info in below.

UnityConfig class:

```
namespace Amir.CodingChallenge.WcfService.Unity
{
    public static class UnityConfig
    {
        static UnityContainer container;
        public static UnityContainer RegisterComponents()
        {
            if (container == null)
                container = new UnityContainer();

            RegisterTypes();

            return container;
        }

        private static void RegisterTypes()
        {
            container.RegisterType<IShowService, ShowService>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        }
    }
}
```

UnityServiceHost class:

```
namespace Amir.CodingChallenge.WcfService.Unity
{
    public class UnityServiceHost : ServiceHost
    {
        public UnityContainer Container { set; get; }

        public UnityServiceHost()
            : base()
        {
            Container = new UnityContainer();
        }

        public UnityServiceHost(Type serviceType, params Uri[] baseAddresses)
            : base(serviceType, baseAddresses)
        {
            Container = new UnityContainer();
        }

        protected override void OnOpening()
        {
            if (this.Description.Behaviors.Find<UnityServiceBehavior>() == null)
                this.Description.Behaviors.Add(new UnityServiceBehavior(Container));

            base.OnOpening();
        }
    }
}
```

UnityServiceBehavior class:

```
namespace Amir.CodingChallenge.WcfService.Unity
{
    public class UnityServiceBehavior : IServiceBehavior
    {
        public UnityInstanceProvider InstanceProvider { get; set; }
        private ServiceHost serviceHost = null;

        public UnityServiceBehavior()
        {
            InstanceProvider = new UnityInstanceProvider();
        }

        public UnityServiceBehavior(UnityContainer unity)
        {
            InstanceProvider = new UnityInstanceProvider();
            InstanceProvider.Container = unity;
        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
        {
            foreach (ChannelDispatcherBase cdb in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers)
            {
                ChannelDispatcher cd = cdb as ChannelDispatcher;
                if (cd != null)
                {
                    foreach (EndpointDispatcher ed in cd.Endpoints)
                    {
                        InstanceProvider.ServiceType = serviceDescription.ServiceType;
                        ed.DispatchRuntime.InstanceProvider = InstanceProvider;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase) { }

        public void AddBindingParameters(
        ServiceDescription serviceDescription,
        ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase,
        Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints,
        BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

UnityInstanceProvider class:

```
namespace Amir.CodingChallenge.WcfService.Unity
{
    public class UnityInstanceProvider : IInstanceProvider
    {
        public UnityContainer Container { set; get; }
        public Type ServiceType { set; get; }

        public UnityInstanceProvider()
            : this(null)
        {
        }

        public UnityInstanceProvider(Type type)
        {
            ServiceType = type;
            Container = new UnityContainer();
        }

        #region IInstanceProvider Members

        public object GetInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext, Message message)
        {
            return Container.Resolve(ServiceType);
        }

        public object GetInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext)
        {
            return GetInstance(instanceContext, null);
        }
        public void ReleaseInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext, object instance)
        {
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us your implementation of UnityServiceHost. Is the type MovieService not registered in the unity container?

Comment: Jon, I've registered IShowService in UnityConfig.RegisterComponents() method not the IMovieService. As I know Unity needs the dependencies to be registered not dependency consumers however I tried to register IMovieService as well and it didn't solve the problem!
I updated my post to show the rest of my codes.

Comment: And ShowService has a parameterless constructor?

Comment: Should the `relativeAddress="./MovieService.svc"` not be `relativeAddress="MovieService.svc"`

Comment: ShowService constructor is parameterless.

Comment: Also I changed relativeAddress to "MovieService.svc" but no success.

Comment: I reckon the problem is that WCF doesn't recognize my custom Service Host Factory. when I change factory attribute in "serviceActivations" section to a dummy value: "blabla" i get the same error on runtime which is complaining about not implementing parameterless MovieService constructor. And if I implement that parameterless constructor, my CreateServiceHost method in UnityServiceHostFactory doesn't get hit.

Comment: Did you make any progress on this @user3651388? I am having an identical issue using a service host factory to initialize my IoC, except I'm using [ninject](http://www.ninject.org)

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that you are linking to the UnityServiceHostFactory in your Service Markup

```
<%@ ServiceHost 
    Language="C#" Debug="true" 
    Service="WcfServiceApplication.Implementation.ProductService" 
    Factory="WcfServiceApplication.DependencyInjection.WCF.UnityServiceHostFactory"
%>
```

Finding the Markup code was the issue for me.  Just right click on the Svc and click "View Markup"
Then you can add in the UnityServiceHostFactory as the Factory value

[image: How to Edit Markup]

[Link to Source of Answer](http://jamesheppinstall.wordpress.com/2012/06/20/windows-communication-foundation-resolving-wcf-service-dependencies-with-unity/)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the build is copying the project dll to the correct location.
In my case, I was copying for 'bin\debug' and the correct would be 'bin\'.